# Why is Matplotlib saved figure only chopping off y axis ticks/numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.plt(....)
plt.xlabel(...)
plt.ylabel(...)
plt.suptitle(...)
plt.figtext(0.415, 0.04, "...")
plt.figtext(0.19, 0.04, "...")
plt.xlim(...)
plt.ylim(...)
plt.xticks(np.arange(...)
plt.yticks(np.arange(...))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major', axis='both')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.plt(....)
plt.xlabel(...)
plt.suptitle(...)
plt.figtext(0.84, 0.04, "...")
plt.figtext(0.6125, 0.04, "...")
plt.xlim(...)
plt.ylim(...)
plt.xticks(np.arange(...)
plt.yticks(np.arange(...))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major', axis='both')
plt.savefig(os.path.join(parentDirectory, "123.png"), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)
```

Here is a sample output, I have blocked out data for privacy reasons.

[image]

I have tried plt.tightlayout() which has not fixed the issue. I have also tried saving as a jpg and that does not work either.

I do not understand how the ylabel is showing but the numbers are not? On ax2, I am intentionally not showing ylabel.

Confusingly, if I use plt.show() I can see my y axis.

I think something odd might be going on with my axes, because my x axis is set to show up to 900, but is only showing 800.

Is it some sort of padding issue? If that was true, surely plt.tightlayout() would have fixed it?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide more code so that this can be reproduced. Short of that, try switching all of your calls with `plt` to the appropriate axes instance. For example, you could try setting the xlim and ylim with `ax1.set_xlim()`, and `ax1.set_ylim()`. Do this for each of the `plt` calls; you will need to consult the documentation to find the appropriate function. What's probably going on is that the calls to `plt.*` after you add the second axis are not doing what you think they are because there are now two axes.

Comment: I agree with K.Shores . You are mixing up the OOP approach through setting your plot via methods attached to an `AxesSubplot` object in ax and the state-machine approach in `matplotlib.pyplot` . There can be surprising side effects if you're not careful. In addition please provide a fully working example that reproduces your problem. Like this it's pretty much guesswork.

Comment: Hello both, thank you for your suggestion. I have changed to ax1 and ax2, however that has not fixed the issue. As I said, it works in plt.show(), however not when I save the figure, which is odd. I understand your point about providing an example, however I cannot due to the nature of the work. I have provided a barebone structure of the code, which is the best I can do.

Comment: Did you change all `plt.` calls with `ax1.set_` calls? That should be the proper way to set everything for the right `AxesSubplot`. You need to find out the equivalence between the OOP call and the `plt` call for each thing you set. That can be quite a hassle. As a rule of thumb: If I do more than one or two plotting calls in a script I use the OOP approach.

Comment: I have yes, there are no plt. calls left in the script. I am trying to comment parts of the code out to see if it works at any point

Comment: I have found the issue. When I call ax1. plot() I am unpacking the result of a function in the plot function, i.e. ax1.plot(*myfunction(arg,arg)). Is this overwriting axes when it does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be caused by a dashed linestyle that I was calling in my ax1.plot() command.
I was using:

```
ax1.plot(*myfunction(args,args),'red','--')
```

which I thought would work, but was doing something odd? Removing the '--' has fixed the issue.

Thanks